# What is this template parsing conflict called?

Tags: c++, templates, name-lookup

I am getting an issue compiling this minimal example with g++ 7.3

```
template<typename T>
struct conflict
{
};

template<typename T>
struct s
{
    int conflict;
};

template<typename T>
bool go()
{
    s<T>* sp;
    return sp->conflict < 0;
}
```

The actual error message is less than revealing:

```
|| test.cpp: In function ‘bool go()’:
test.cpp|16 col 24| error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T> struct conflict’
||   return sp->conflict < 0;
||                         ^
test.cpp|16 col 24| note:   expected a type, got ‘0’
```

In truth the compiler is trying to instantiate the `conflict` template instead of comparing the `conflict` field.

Does this error have a name?

Also, I fixed it by swapping the comparison to use `>`.  Is there a better way?

Comment: It's still a type mismatch, is it not?

Comment: I'm tempted to say this is a bug but I'm not sure.  clang and gcc both error but MSVS compiles fine.  `return (sp->conflict) < 0;` gets it to compile with both clang and gcc.

Comment: Very literally, I suppose, but the "error" to me is tied to intent: it isn't the programmer's intent that 0 ought to be a type, but rather that `conflict` should be referring to the field.

Comment: Compilers do not read programmer's intent, they read programmer's code.

Comment: No, [this sample code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d6e67699e0fcf37) may be interesting.  The one with `sp->conflict<T>` becomes correct.  (and yes, yours has a `0;` instead of `T>::x;`, but the compiler shouldn't have to look that far ahead to know if `<` starts a template parameter list, or is `operator<`.)

Comment: This is a variant of [core issue 1835](https://wg21.link/CWG1835).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [T.C. pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53639166/what-is-this-template-parsing-conflict-called/53639931#comment94138456_53639166) this is the subject of [CWG active issue 1835](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1835) which says:

> According to 6.4.5 [basic.lookup.classref] paragraph 1,
>
> > In a class member access expression (8.2.5 [expr.ref]), if the . or -> token is immediately followed by an identifier followed by a <, the identifier must be looked up to determine whether the < is the
> >     beginning of a template argument list (17.2 [temp.names]) or a
> >     less-than operator. The identifier is first looked up in the class of
> >     the object expression. If the identifier is not found, it is then
> >     looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression and shall
> >     name a class template.
>
> Given
>
> ```
>    template<typename T> T end(T);
>    template<typename T>
>    bool Foo(T it) {
>      return it->end < it->end;
>    }
> ```
>
> since it is dependent and thus end cannot be looked up in the class of
>   the object expression, it is looked up in the context of the
>   postfix-expression. This lookup finds the function template, making
>   the expression ill-formed.
>
> One possibility might be to limit the lookup to the class of the
>   object expression when the object expression is dependent.

A fix is to use `()`:

```
return (sp->conflict) < 0;
```

[see it live on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/p50xnV)